# Phonegap Tabbar. When window.open is called, TabBar loses functionality

Tags: ios, cordova, tabbar

I am relatively new to the world of JS and Phone Gap. I am using the Native TabBar plugin on my app which is working perfectly however when one of my tabs calls:

```
 function TabPressed(){

  window.open('www.google.com', '_self', 'location=no');
 }
```

My TabBar loses its functionality. I guess this is because the window.open is opening a new webpage with new js etc... how do I still allow my tabBar to function when a new window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

using `window.open` you are loading a new page, leaving the old page completely(with scripts and styles), so the listeners that you attached to TabBar are gone.

You should keep this code available at all times. If you need to load external web pages, load them using [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser) plugin.

Or have a local page(index.html) and include all phonegap related scripts in this page. When you need to open a new page, use ajax and insert the html into a container `div` in this already loaded page. Most of Phonegap applications use this approach.